# Is it possible to install an app and exclude some of its requested permissions?

Tags: applications, permissions, installation

Occasionally I want to install an application which requires certain permissions that I feel it really shouldn't need. Can I install the app without giving it these permissions? For example, GPS location, [phone state](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/605/why-do-so-many-android-applications-require-permission-to-use-the-phone), internet connection, etc.

Is it possible to change the permissions of an application once it is installed?

Comment: Here's a related question worth keeping an eye on: [Are there any tools to sandbox a malware application even more than the granted permissions on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3294)

Comment: another related question [Revoking permissions for an android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836155/revoking-permissions-for-an-android-app/14178216)

Comment: Related: [Revoke App Permissions Without Root?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24101/)

Answer (score 30):

### Prior to Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean)

No. Without a custom ROM it's an all-or-nothing affair. Which is part of the reason Google encourages developers to ensure that they're asking for the absolute minimum permissions required for the app to work.

Short of getting the app code and modifying it, you either need to accept the access request or not use the app. [Some alternatives exist](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_1028) if your device is rooted.

### Android 4.3/4.4 (partly also 5.x)

There's a semi-hidden permissions manager (App Ops) that can be reached through a [third-party app](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Appops&c=apps), but doesn't require root or a custom ROM. Android Police has covered it [here](https://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/25/app-ops-android-4-3s-hidden-app-permission-manager-control-permissions-for-individual-apps/).

Note, however, that Google has said that this was released in error, and newer versions of Android have once again disabled this.

### Android 4.4+

Additionally to above mentioned *App Ops*, here you can also use the [Xposed Framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053) (for Android 5+ [see here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811)) with modules like [Xprivacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy) or [Protect My Privacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.synergylabs.androidpmp). While this will require your device to be rooted, it offers additional functionality.

### Android 6+

*marcioggs* outlined [functionalities provided in Android M](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/111579/16575) in a separate answer.

Comment: If you root, you can exclude network access with DroidWall, but that's a specific exception.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google decided to group things which a lot of entertainment applications need such as determining if there's call active, under the same permission as things which very few non-phone-functionality applications need, such as determining the phone number.

Answer (score 17):

CyanogenMod 7 supports this. It activated by going to `Settings->CyanogenMod Settings->Applications` and checking "Permission management" as of the most recent build. You can then allow and disallow permissions by choosing an app from the app management list (`Settings->Applications->Manage applications`). There is an [article on endgaget](http://www.engadget.com/2011/05/24/new-cyanogenmod-lets-you-rule-android-app-permissions-with-an-ir/) with a Youtube demonstration.

**Disclaimer:** This may be obvious to some, but denying permissions to an app could have fairly crash-tastic consequences. Nonetheless, if you have a device that is supported by CM and you are willing to root and install it, you can enjoy permission-by-permission control (and any hazards that come with it).

In fact, due to the crashes that the permission management implementation tended to cause, it was removed from the CyanogenMod codebase in version 9. However, the most recent nightly builds of CyanogenMod 10.1 now include a feature that has been dubbed "[Privacy Guard](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/06/24/privacy-guard-formerly-incognito-mode-has-been-merged-into-cyanogenmod-will-appear-in-nightlies-starting-today/)". Instead of *blocking* apps from accessing data that they request, Privacy Guard will provide them with *blank* data.

As an example, if an app running under Privacy Guard requests your contacts list, CM will simply return an empty list, causing the app to functionally believe that you don't have any contacts stored on your phone.

Comment: Sadly, faking data is not considered for integration into CyanogenMod.

Answer (score 8):

There is an [App Shield](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gmail.exathink.appshield&feature=search_result) application. It essentially repackages .apk with permissions removed from [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html). Brilliant idea for stock, non rooted phones. Subject to crashes (force closes), though, as with CyanogenMod (as of version 7).

---

**Update:** *App Shield* seems no longer to be maintained. It currently can be found in some "personal Aptoide repositories", e.g. at [Mixal](http://m.mixal.store.aptoide.com/app/market/com.gmail.exathink.appshield/7/6431515/App+Shield) and [Karbyfio](http://m.karbyfio.store.aptoide.com/app/market/com.gmail.exathink.appshield/8/2074302/App+Shield). It is recommended to rather use something more up-to-date now.

Answer (score 7):

**NOTE:** *LBE Privacy Guard* is no longer maintained and only available for Android versions below 4.2.

**Warning:** if you are on Jelly Bean (Android 4.1+), be sure to check whether LBE has been updated for Jelley Bean yet. At the moment (July 27 2012) it is still incompatible, and it will cause your device to **boot loop on Jelly Bean.** That means you may have to factory-reset your device. **[Xprivacy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.bokhorst.xprivacy.installer)** is now recommended instead (root required).

---

[LBE Privacy Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite) can block specific permissions per application, both during installation and afterwards. This is the English version of an apparently Chinese application that has existed for a while (I am not in any way affiliated to them); it already has over 100,000 downloads. I haven't tried it yet, but I plan to do so tomorrow.

You can also set it to, say, have Facebook display a prompt (yes/no) when it wants to access your location, etc. A screenshot from the Play Store:

[image]

Comment: Doesen't work on Xperia ray with CM 10.0. **I just had to re-install my device!**

Comment: @rubo77: Ouch, that sucks! (Did you read my warning at the top?)

Comment: Yes, but I thought I might get away with it ;) You should add, that there is no way to recover a bootloop and that it doesen't work on many devices. looking at the feedback in Play store, exactly half the votes are 5 and halv are 1, so I guess every second device will fail

Comment: @rubo77: So it hasn't been updated for more than a year, then? I haven't used it since I made that edit...I now use Xprivacy. As to recovering from a boot loop, there are ways. You could for example boot into recovery and remove the application through a file manager / your PC. Maybe then reflash your ROM.

Comment: Sure, I meant "no way to recover a bootloop without loosing all your settings". I will try [Xprivacy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.bokhorst.xprivacy.installer) now, sounds promising

Comment: @rubo77: If you remove the application and/or reflash your ROM, if that works, you shouldn't lose your settings. Goof luck with Xprivacy!

Comment: The second link is dead, unfortunately. Answer needs an update.

Comment: @Firelord: Ah, now I understand: the link is only accessible for me because I once installed it. When I log out of my Google account, I can't access the page either. However, there is no other location for the software in the Play Store. The only alternative is the Chinese version in the Play Store, which is up to date but unusable for non-Chinese speakers. So I have no other link. Everything in my answer under the vertical line is outdated and is kept for archival purposes only. Just use Xprivacy: it is better in many ways.

Answer (score 6):

The following functionalities will be provided in Android M:

- Give specific permissions as needed during rutime;
- Show an app's permission;
- Show all apps that uses a specific permission.

**Documentation for M preview:**

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html

**Permissions screen:**

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Xposed Framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1574401) along with the [App Settings Module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) to deny application permissions. You can also use it to change DPI settings allowing apps to run in tablet mode on phones and vice versa (along with changing the size of things in general). It works beautifully for me. You will need root to install it, though.

Thanks to [Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16575/izzy) for pointing out the need for a module. As per their comment you can also use [Xprivacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy) or [Protect My Privacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.synergylabs.androidpmp) to achieve this control.

Comment: At the time this answer was written the app settings module came bundled with most xposed framework installations. That module supports this functionality.

Comment: Thanks to you for still caring for your "old answers" – +1 for that :) So we shall cleanup (delete) our comments then :) PS: Please leave your first, it still makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this app called [Permission Remover](https://www.plop.at/en/android/permission-remover.html) that allows you to remove permissions from the APK package before installing it. Worked for both installed and downloaded APKs. This method is convenient as it does not require you to root your device.

Answer (score 0):

Fine-grained app permissions are not present in stock builds of Android up to version 5.1.1. Google has introduced a new permissions model starting with 6.0 that includes some control based on permission groups. However, if you've gained root access on a device running version 5.1.1 or below, there are options for adding this feature to your device.

1. Xposed Framework

Head over to [xda-developers.com](http://xda-developers.com) and search for "xposed framework" to get info on how to install the framework. After installing the framework, install either the [XPrivacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy) or the [App Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) modules to get more control over each app and their granted permissions.

2. Install a Cyanogenmod-based ROM

Go to [Cyanogenmod Downloads](https://download.cyanogenmod.org) and see if your device is listed. If it isn't, head back to [xda-developers.com](http://xda-developers.com) and go to your devices forum page to find a list of ROMs for your device. Look for anything referring to "cyanogenmod" or "cm" in the original post of a ROM thread to find the right base to give permission control access.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A good app (which is not in in playstore anymore since 2016) by [root uninstaller](https://web.archive.org/web/20120326063601/http://rootuninstaller.com/root-firewall/): To withdraw an app just the right to enter internet in CyanogenMod you can use [Root Firewall](https://apkpure.com/root-firewall/com.rootuninstaller.firewall) (needs root).

It can block internet access for any apps.

The free version can already block either all apps or just block up to 7 distinct apps.