# Why does every app has/needs the permission "Send MMS" and "Send Email"?

Tags: applications, permissions

So, I recently bought Elephone P8000 which has Android 5.1 installed. One of the first things I noticed was the new "App Permissions". After installing a few of my standard apps, I was curious and checked the app permissions, and I was quite surprised when I saw that every app had the permissions "Send MMS" and "Send Email".

I could understand that if it were only WhatsApp, obviously, a chat app might need this permission. But even my GBA Emulator or the Fallout Pip-Boy app had this permission even though they don't have any kind of communication functionality.

So what is the point of these 2 permissions? Why does every app need those?

[image: App Permission Screenshot]

Comment: Honestly, I checked [Fallout Pip-Boy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bethsoft.falloutcompanionapp)'s permission on Play Store ( I even installed it to check), and there is no "Send MMS" nor "Send Email". From where did you install it? It was probably modified by hacker and it really worried me...

Comment: @AndrewT. I installed it from the official google play store, released by Bethesda Softworks LLC. I added a screenshot from the app permissions to show what i meant.

Comment: Hmm, it didn't occur on my Nexus 5, Marshmallow 6.0. What is your device model, also are you perhaps using custom ROM (Check on Settings - About)?

Comment: Could this be some sort of permission misallocation (even as wrong as it sounds)?

Comment: @AndrewT. I got the Elephone P8000, quite unknown, but a good model. It also tells me that i run Android Version 5.1. It doesn't look like this is some kind of custom firmware.

Comment: Also, just FYI, "App permissions" is not implemented until AOSP Android 6.0 Marshmallow, so I'd believe this is running on custom ROM. Unfortunately, I have no clue how to know what's the ROM name.

Comment: @AndrewT. Think it is Flyme ROM going by [forums](http://bbs.elephone.hk/search.php?mod=forum&searchid=118&orderby=lastpost&ascdesc=desc&searchsubmit=yes&kw=flyme&mobile=2)

Comment: Not that every app in the Play Store has declared those permissions, neither we can verify that your test is true and every user installed app in your device asks for that permissions. Consider backing this broad statement. You can use some permissions explorer app(s) to list installed apps based on specific permissions. (Use [my answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/117292/96277), if needed). Also, give us the list of all the user installed apps too. I can't believe that broad claim without any proof.

Comment: @Firelord well, if needed, I can screenshot the permissions of every app I currently have installed on my device if that's needed.

Answer (score 8):

Intrigued by this question, I searched in the forums and found a similar query,which probably explains, at least in part, of what you are seeking.

[Preventing installed apps from making calls or sending SMS](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23731/preventing-installed-apps-from-making-calls-or-sending-sms)

<sub>Almost verbatim from the answer by @ Steven Roose (all credits to him)</sub>

Developers sometimes grant their apps permission which their apps in fact don't need. If you are aware and you don't agree with this trend, the only thing you can do is not download such apps. Or even better, you can consider contacting the developer of the application and ask him why this permission is required. Maybe they are not aware of the fact and are very willing to remove the permission if they can please their users by doing so.

A to-do list should not have the permission to send SMS messages, if I see a to-do app that requires this permission myself, I would just look for another app to use.

My "guess", is that app developers ask for them just in case it is required in future, though the app may not need or use them currently. It might even be that the developer has requested an inclusive permission (for example, `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` implies that `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` has also been granted, and both permissions will show up for the app); although this might not be true in your case.

Also, one point: It might be a device-specific or case-specific (one-time) issue. Try uninstalling and reinstalling all relevant apps to check.

EDIT

ELEPONE 8000 runs a custom ROM as per [Android Authority](http://www.androidauthority.com/elephone-p8000-review-634638/).

"The Elephone P8000 runs Android 5.1 Lollipop out of the box, with the custom Elephone UI on top"

ROM appears to be Flyme as per [this forum](http://bbs.elephone.hk/search.php?mod=forum&searchid=118&orderby=lastpost&ascdesc=desc&searchsubmit=yes&kw=flyme&mobile=2) (search for Flyme)

Does this explain the discrepancy of app displaying different permissions as discussed in comments to the question?

EDIT 2

As [tested](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129179/why-does-every-app-has-needs-the-permission-send-mms-and-send-email/129186#comment160740_129179)  by Andrew T, I have repeated that by downloading from play store and the app does not have "send MMS " or "send email" permissions accorded. This leads to the conclusion that the observations made by OP are ROM / UI specific.

Reasons for the ROM/UI causing this could be a topic for separate question

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks for the answer. This was my initial guess too, but then I tried to imagine why an emulator would ever need to send e-mails or MMS. And EVERY app has those. I can't really believe that every developer want's their apps to send mails in the future.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury I'm tired, yes, i wanted, I'm sorry. xD

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury While this is a good answer, it didn't answer my question completely. I still can't really believe that every developer want's their apps to send mails in the future, as I stated in the comment I accidentally sent to you.

Comment: Alright, I didn't even know that there is a custom ui. I guess this is the reason why Evers app got that Perkussion, i think i have to dig for those informations. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I would, but I have no idea how to do that on the app. I'll be at home tomorrow, I'll accept your answer then.

Comment: @Steven Roose. Belated but didn't mark you when I attributed your post. Thanks for inputs