# Is there a way to block permissions for other applications on Jelly Bean?

Tags: security, 4.1-jelly-bean, permissions, privacy

I use [LBE Privacy Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite&feature=search_result) with great pleasure to grant and withdraw permissions to access my contacts, the internet, etc. for each individual application installed in Ice-Cream Sandwich on my Galaxy Nexus. However, it is not compatible with Jelly Bean yet (causes rebooting cycle without fixing, and even then it can only block network access). Considering that the last update was in March of this year, this may take a while.

Is there another application that can do this and that is compatible with Jelly Bean? Applications like Droidwall and Permission Denied and others also don't seem to work on JB. [This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/are-there-any-tools-to-sandbox-a-malware-application-even-more-than-the-granted) asks a similar question, but that was a year ago, and I believe none of those application works on Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 1):

On the forum of XDA Developers, an unofficial version of LBE is available. It works very well on 4.1.1 and 4.1.1, at least on my Galaxy Nexus, and people on the forum are enthusiastic about it too. Many people are using it. I appears to be the Chinese version, which is still under active development and up to date, but translated by volunteers on XDA. Highly recommended.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1422479