# How to prevent Spotify to access photo/media?

Tags: cyanogenmod, permissions

Spotify recently changed their policy and want to collect private data like contacts and photos/media.

I am using Cyanogen OS which has the cm permission manager. I can disable access to contacts for any app.

Since I never used an app that wanted access to my media I am not sure if the cm permission manager can prevent that too.

So how can you prevent access to media on devices with CM?(mine is rooted)

Comment: [XPrivacy](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy#description) is all you need. You may check-out [this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/21359/14045) too. Some answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3294/96277) may also help out.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the desired result with the [XPrivacy](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy) module, part of the XPosed framework.

I can precisely remove permissions from any app. In case the app relies on those permissions to work I can generate false values.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

As you can see I am able to remove the permission to use the Internet or I can go deeper and remove specific functions if needed. Furthermore I can decide upon app usage of a permission, which means whenever an app tries to use a permission I am asked once if I want to allow or decline this.

However this is not recommended to people who are afraid of resetting or reflashing their devices if needed. XPosed goes deep into the system of Android. It runs stable but regular backups are a must, just in case.

Comment: XPrivacy doesn't remove the permissions asked by an app but simply restricts access to permissions (the data) when access is demanded by the app. See the app's description. There is a difference between removing and restricting here. Restriction here means that if the XPrivacy module is removed from the system or is somehow made not to run, then the app (previously restricted) would normally work and be able to access what it demanded under the constraints of Android. Removing the permissions implies that the app wouldn't be able to access permissions regardless of the state of XPrivacy.

Answer (score -4):

Try this app if it can help : http://m.lizardo.store.aptoide.com/app/market/com.stericson.permissions.donate/4/3204650/Permissions+Denied+Pro

Comment: Some more information about the app would be useful, such as how to use the app, what does it do that the CM permission manager doesn't etc... Link-only answers are not encouraged since they are useless if the link dies