# How do I withdraw an app rights to enter internet in CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, permissions

On a rooted device it should be possible to forbid certain apps to contact internet connection

How is this possible in CyanogenMod 10.0?

Comment: [Block apps from accessing the Internet on Android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/40924), [Is it possible to install an app and exclude some of its requested permissions?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3091)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An app like [Root Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.firewall&hl=en) (needs root) should work.

> ☆ Block Internet access for any apps:

Answer (score 0):

on CM

Go to Settings > Applications

Open the application you want to restrict. Scroll down to the permissions section and strike off internet access by clicking on the permission.

Alternatively you could use an application like LBE privacy guard to restrict access.

With this method you can restrict any permission.

Sometimes apps start force-closing when you revoke permissions so be careful!

Comment: you cannot click on the permissions in CM10. I used XPrivacy now, cause LBE privacy destroys CyanogenMod on my phone (see http://android.stackexchange.com/a/25818/22975 )

Comment: Does not work in CM11 either. There is a "privacy guard", but for ""some suspicious reason"" it does not have network connections.