# Which Android version/phone can control per-app access permission?

Tags: security, privacy

The only reason I am still using an iPhone is due to the fact that most Android phones did not allow control of per-app access permission. The [App Ops feature](http://www.cnet.com/news/why-android-wont-be-getting-app-ops-anytime-soon/) was once there but pulled.

I know some Chinese Android phones, such as XiaoMi and Huawei, provide the app permission feature. Is the feature available in *mainstream* Android phones, such as the Nexus, Samsung, LG, HTC ... for latest version of Android 4.4.2 or upcoming Android L?

Comment: [Is it possible to install an app and exclude some of its requested permissions?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/is-it-possible-to-install-an-app-and-exclude-some-of-its-requested-permissions?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, App Ops is not available on Android any more since Android v4.4.2 and probably won't be reintroduced with Android L** but might be resurrected some time later. It was apparently dropped as some apps would stop functioning so the user experience would suffer.

Some optimal solutions:

- Find a device that is supported by a Custom ROM like Cyanogenmod. This aftermarket firmware includes a feature called **[Privacy Guard](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Why_Mod%3F#Why_use_CyanogenMod.3F)** that works similar to App Ops.
- *My preferred solution:* Buy a phone that is rootable and use the 3rd party solution called **[Xprivacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy)**. It is an Xposed module that has the most advanced permission control with a very dedicated developer. As long as your device is rooted you will be able to use that tool on any ROM > Android v4.0. Downside: Not easy to handle.
- Use one of the other optional methods for permission management listed and compared by the Xprivacy developer [here](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy/blob/master/README.md#similar-solutions).