# Can I trust MoboClean to deny specific permissions of other apps?

Tags: applications, security, permissions

A couple of articles on the Internet about how to block specific application permissions refer to some app called [MoboClean](http://moboclean.com/).

It doesn't seem very popular and well-known trusted-by-users app so I wanted to ask for some more expert opinion about how safe this app is (it's not open source AFAIK) and whether should I bother installing it at all.

Moreover, it's not provided in the android market; you have to download the apk yourself and install it manually, which leads me to additional suspicion.

Comment: For alternatives to that app, see http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3091/96277

Comment: If any task can be done by the user without any app, then I prefer doing it that way. Installing an app that is not quite popular (like the one you're saying) has the risk of bringing in adware in your device. If you don't have infinite number of apps, then I think you should manually deny permissions from the apps rather than depend on another app.