# Questions About Android Privacy

Tags: security, permissions, privacy

The permissions warning in the Android Market is very vague. As well, I can't see the app permissions in a collective area of all the apps I have previously installed. So, I have no clue whether an app is accessing my contacts, my email address, my name, phone number, camera, microphone, image gallery, and other private information.

Is there a way, or an app I can install, which will indicate some risks to me about my apps and my privacy?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3308/audit-app-permissions-easily-in-one-place

Comment: http://bit.ly/2OprA7s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **can** see the permissions of installed apps.  Go to

```
Market -> Menu button, My apps -> select an app -> Menu button, Security
```

There are also apps called Permissions Watchdog, and Permissions, as per Al's comment.

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3308/audit-app-permissions-easily-in-one-place

Answer (score 3):

(This may be OS version dependant)

If you go into **Settings** -> **Applications** -> **Manage Applications**, you should be able to click on any app whether you installed it via the Market or "side-loaded" it, and there's a Permissions section if you scroll down that lists them all.