# wifi is getting turned off and mobile data is getting turned on automatically

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, mobile-data, background-data

I am facing a weird scenario in my android phone since 2-3 days.

My wi-fi is automatically getting turned off and my mobile data pack is getting turned on.

It has been cost effective 2-3 days.

I have followed different questions on Android forum and stackexchange it self.

I am listing out the suggestions, i have already tried:-

1. Disable battery saver app
   (I dont have any battery saver app installed)
2. Did restrict background data for each and every app installed on my phone
   (As many blogs were suggesting the same)

Still am facing this issue.

Model-Micromax A310
Android Version - 4.4.2

Comment: try after reset device after backup

Comment: Can you mention which apps in your device are granted  `CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE` and `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` permissions? (Optionally, see [Is there a native way to find all the installed apps that have access to a phone feature?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/129470) || [How can I find which apps/packages reference a given permission using command line?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/117292))

Comment: Did you turn off "connections optimizer" in phone settings?

Comment: Check for advance options for _auto turn off_ in wifi connection app.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in the Wi-Fi settings:
**Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep**

It has the following options:
-> Always
-> Only when plugged in
-> Never

Make sure the above is set to "Always".
I believe it will have set "Never" in your case.