# Check which app triggers WIFI on

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, 5.1-lollipop, oneplus-one

I have a Oneplus One device with Cyanogen OS 12.1.

The issue is that my battery history shows that my wifi is always on gets on after sometime and then never closes.

I did not turn my wifi on manually nor is the option `"SCANNING ALWAYS available"` is set on.

So I think that there must be some app which is triggering it or it may even be a CM issue. How to know what is causing this?

There are similar questions on this forum but none of them answers my query.

I have tried `adb logcat | tee wifi.log`  to check what is triggering the wifi but couldnt find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check in advance setting option of wifi. There may be auto on-off. You need to change it as you pleased.

Comment: Is your phone rooted? If yes, you could use Tasker app to set off your WiFi whenever it becomes ON.

Comment: Use a [permissions checker app](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions) or [command-line](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131519/wifi-is-getting-turned-off-and-mobile-data-is-getting-turned-on-automatically/131567#comment164315_131519) to determine which apps can toggle Wi-Fi in your device. That may help you to focus on specific apps only.

Comment: ok i have factory reset the device, but it is still happening. Once i restart the device the wifi turns off but again it when i toggle wifi on/off it wont turn off