# Why does an app read my phone's IMEI number? An awful lot of them do

Tags: permissions, imei

What reasons should an app have to need my phone's International Mobile Equipment Identity number?  I noticed that unreasonably many of ordinary apps have the "phone state and identity" permission.  For example, Remember the Milk.  What do they ask it for?  Am I insufficiently paranoid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do so many android applications require permission to use the phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/605/why-do-so-many-android-applications-require-permission-to-use-the-phone)

Comment: See this answer: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/3368/440

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many apps use the IMEI for analytics purposes, for example counting users. Most tools like Google Analytics or Flurry need a unique ID per phone, so the IMEI fits quite well.

Note that this doesn't work on non-cellular platforms (like tablets), and the IMEI can also be faked: this is why some apps choose a different system (see [this article](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1662)).

Answer (score 3):

It's often used to identify the unique phone, but often this is actually quite a bad idea. Most apps would be better off identifying you as a user, who can use multiple different devices on one account.