# Should I be worried about applications with weird looking permissions?

Tags: security, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How important is it to review the permissions that an app is using?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/how-important-is-it-to-review-the-permissions-that-an-app-is-using)

When I install apps from Android Market (Play Store now) there are some apps that require special permissions and for some of them it's weird to have for example "Read phone call history" when the app is a compass or whatever...

Should I be worried? Should I uninstall an app with weird looking permissions?

Comment: This question can nobody answer. Should you be worried? Maybe. Does the app "bad" stuff with the permission you grant? If the App isn't open source, then nobody can tell and all you can do is trust the publisher/developer or not.

Comment: See also: [Why do so many android applications require permission to read the phone state and identity?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/605/) and [How important is it to review the permissions that an app is using?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/)

Comment: This does seem like it would be covered by one of several existing questions. Have you read those? Do you have some additional questions that are not covered in the previous ones?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should be worried.  Lots of malware disguises itself as something else that the writer thinks you might want to install so that it can get the app onto your phone.  If you are at all suspicious about permissions (and reading phone history is definitely suspicious for a compass app), contact the app developer with your questions.  An honest dev will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely requires some sensible judgement. If the app is from a trusted dev (Top Devloper with that symbol) then you can be rest assured that that app isn't any malware. Generally, apps which look shady in terms of title and comments are the ones you must proceed with caution.

Comment: Famous apps also ask for excess permission. PPS (5,000,000+ downloads) needs READ PHONE STATUS AND IDENTITY, READ CALL LOG, READ YOUR CONTACTS, ... add more.