# Why does this ad keep showing up below my notification bar and how do I stop it?

Tags: applications, ads

I keep getting an ad that shows up BELOW my notification bar. It is NOT in the notifications, nor on the homescreen, as far as I can tell.

I am using CyanogenMod 12.1 nightlies on a HTC M8. Screenshots below.

How can I get rid of this thing? It just showed up one day. I don't remember installing anything new (although I have autoupdate on for apps, and some update very often) right before it started. I tried ad scanners, but they haven't been much help.

I would rather not factory reset.

I can close the ad by clicking the small "x". If I click on the info button in the lower left corner, I can give feedback on the specific ad and ask not to see it again. If I click on opt out, it asks for my IMEI, which I'm not really comfortable providing.

The ads are all in Hungarian and Romanian. I live in Romania, close to the Hungarian border, so I'm guessing that is why.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

Opt out page:

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Since you are running CM, you can go into privacy settings and look for all apps with permission to draw over the screen.

Comment: If an app has the permissions to override the notification drawer it (probably) can get the IMEI, so supplying it wouldn't be a *huge* issue.

Comment: @Chipperyman Technically getting the IMEI requires a separate permission ([“Read phone status and identity”](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE)); however, [this permission is required by lots of apps](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/605/11251) (see the discussion there for several reason why it might be needed).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many complaints about the [Premium Wallpapers HD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pixign.premiumwallpapers) app, which apparently started to show ads looking like this after its latest update.

In general, an Android app can draw anything over other apps if it has the “Draw over other apps” permission, so you can check which of your installed apps have this permission.

Answer (score 1):

Those ads are shown because of some installed apps in your phone, like Applock. These apps are always run in background and, after some interval of time, the ad is shown again. First find the app(s) which show those ads. Then uninstall those app(s).

Comment: I have this same problem. How do I find out which app to uninstall?

Answer (score 1):

The above two answer are correct but 
1."Draw over other apps” may be but didnt stop the ads for me.
2.we know some apps at the background ruuning the ads but how to find that app?

For me the ads came on whatsapp which is the only  opened app at front end but i know the ads are not from whatsapp.

To find the ads respective app use network connections monitoring app.while you got the ads open the network app and from list try to figure out the  culprit and uninstall those app.pls note some important app will always run and we need to use our guess and trial error resolve this ads problem