# Got stuck with a Pop-up on the main screen

Tags: applications, 5.1-lollipop, uninstallation, popup

I have Samsung Galaxy E5 (SM-E500H) with Android 5.1.1. Recently, I installed few apps and after that, I encountered an annoying little pop-up below the screen sometimes. I got into uninstalling some of those apps but the pop-up didn't go away. How can I get rid of that? More technically, how can I find out which process is the cause of that?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the helpful comments. Answer to: [Determine which app is drawing on top of other apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127769/determine-which-app-is-drawing-on-top-of-other-apps/127862#127862) helped me a lot. I monitored the apps having special permission to put an overlay on top of other apps. I waited until the pop-up showed and with a little compare with the preceding apps list I could find the causing app. Thanks @Firelord.

So, I want to expose the app that caused this unwanted and annoying pop-up:

> Official name: Premium Wallpapers HD
>
> Package name: com.pixign.premiumwallpapers
>
> Play Store link:
>   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pixign.premiumwallpapers&hl=en

Comment: Interesting. So you finally found the troublemaker. I vaguely remember that the poster of the question where the linked answer exists also found the same app as the troublemaker. They mentioned it in a (currently deleted) comment. There's more. The same app has been discussed here: [Why does this ad keep showing up below my notification bar and how do I stop it?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/124880) I advise everyone to use that app carefully.

Comment: Yeah, finally! It's interesting to say when I was watching videos, it sometimes paused the video for no reason and strangely NOT showing its popup (maybe doing other malicious things!?). Btw, thanks @Firelord, your answer really helped.

Answer (score 1):

That AD seems similar to the Google ADs. It's not related to TouchWiz. My suggestion is to search through your installed apps for something that may seem suspicious, or that requires too many permissions, and uninstall it.

Furthermore, I know of no apps that do overlay an existing application with ads, so be careful to not have installed some malware. Since I can see the CM Security antivirus, you should enable the heuristics in the app and scan your system.

Lastly, if your device is rooted, I recommend to install an AD blocker app.

Comment: I did all of what you said; I uninstalled 3 malicious-look-a-like apps; I activated real-time protection and deep heuristic lookup of CM. But at last, the problem still didn't disappear.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Yes it is. I forgot to say, I also installed AD Blocker but for no reason it didn't block this popup (or at least the inner advertisement that popup held).

Comment: If this is the case, my only other idea is to both install an app called "Lucky Patcher", which will tell you what applications are loaded with Google Ads, and another called "Titanium Backup", which (since you're root), can backup a whole app plus its data.

Comment: Next, edit Titanium's preferences, by finding an option called "Backup app external data", and set it to "Always". Then, by looking at Lucky Patcher, firstly backup and then uninstall any app which uses Google Ads, one at a time. Anytime you uninstall something, reboot your device and check if the problem has been solved. If no, then restore the deleted app, and proceed this way till the problem is solved.