# Auto IMEI randomization in Android (like WiFi MAC randomization)

Tags: wi-fi, security, privacy, imei, aosp

How do I set the IMEI number to automatically randomly change every time I connect to a cellular network?

Android 9 introduced a feature that was a huge boon to the privacy of Android users: WiFi MAC Address Randomization.

- https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-mac-randomization

> Starting in Android 8.0, Android devices use randomized MAC addresses when probing for new networks while not currently associated with a network. In Android 9, you can enable a developer option (it's disabled by default) to cause the device to use a randomized MAC address when connecting to a Wi-Fi network.
>
> In Android 10, MAC randomization is enabled by default for client mode, SoftAp, and Wi-Fi Direct.
>
> MAC randomization prevents listeners from using MAC addresses to build a history of device activity, thus increasing user privacy.

As stated, this feature is enabled by default in >= Android 10. So now when you connect to a WiFi network, the owner of the WiFi networks are less able to track your activity between networks.

- MAC addresses are the unique identifier of the hardware device that connects to a WiFi network.
- IMEI numbers are are the unique identifier of the hardware device that connects to a cellular network.

While this change in Android 9/10 greatly increases a user's privacy on WiFi networks (ie MAC randomization), I've seen no such improvements to increase a user's privacy on cellular networks (ie IMEI randomization).

IMEI randomization is especially important in-light of recent research discovering that loads of PII (including IMEI numbers) are being uploaded to both Google and Apple on average every 4.5 minutes

- https://www.scss.tcd.ie/doug.leith/apple_google.pdf

> Abstract — We  investigate  what  data  iOS  on  an  iPhone  shares with  Apple  and  what  data  Google  Android  on  a  Pixel  phone shares with Google. We find that even when minimally configured and  the  handset  is  idle  both  iOS  and  Google  Android  share data  with  Apple/Google  on  average  every  4.5  mins.  The  phone IMEI,  hardware  serial  number,  SIM  serial  number  and  IMSI, handset  phone  number  etc  are  shared  with  Apple  and  Google. Both  iOS  and  Google  Android  transmit  telemetry,  despite  the user  explicitly  opting  out  of  this.  When  a  SIM  is  inserted  both iOS and Google Android send details to Apple/Google. iOS sends the  MAC  addresses  of  nearby  devices,  e.g.  other  handsets  and the  home  gateway,  to  Apple  together  with  their  GPS  location. Users  have  no  opt  out  from  this  and  currently  there  are  few,  if any,  realistic  options  for  preventing  this  data sharing.

Similar to the WiFi MAC randomization feature, how can I setup IMEI randomization? If this is not currently possible, when is it being planned to be added to AOSP?

Comment: [Read more](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/605/131553) to understand why apps ask for IMEI info (though answers are dated, they are valid), so if you randomize them apps may misbehave, as in, music app not pausing when you get a phone call // If you still want to do that, root your phone, install Edxposed modules like XPrivacyLua // *when is it being planned to be added to AOSP* - ask Google, not here-no one here can answer that

Comment: IMEI is used for legal purposes e.g. to identify mobile theft and to enforce carrier agreements wit users. I don't think it'll happen ever.

Comment: MAC addresses are used for legal purposes e.g. to identify a device on a wifi network. I didn't think WiFi MAC randomization would ever be baked-into AOSP and enabled by default, but here we are. It seems at least some of the architects at Google care about privacy

Comment: MAC address is used to identify a device in a local network, just for the purpose of DHCP IP assignment and L2 routing in Ethernet protocol. IMEIs are used to identify devices by MNOs who operate at global level. There are authorities who allocate IMEIs. And IMEI cloning is a crime in many countries. So MAC and IMEI cannot be compared. They are entirely different types of identifiers.

Comment: But your concern is valid. Govt. agencies use IMEI to track you. This must be circumvented. But IMEI randomization doesn't seem to be an option. Even if it is, there are other ways to track you. The entirely isolated operating systems of SIM (Java) card and baseband processors of 3G/4G modems. Who known what runs inside them.

Comment: It should be noted that oppressive governments aren't the only issue. Of course there's many that have a history of violating human rights, dragnet collection of innocent people's PII, and also having this data stolen in breaches. But there's also countless malicious apps that use IMEI numbers to track & sell user's data without their permission. And malicious multinational corporations that have been found guilty of the same. The point is: the best way to keep your data safe is to make it useless -- either by widespread adoption of randomization (eg MAC) or standardization (eg Tor Browser).

Comment: Since Android 10 normal user apps cannot read IMEI: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids. So it's no more a big issue. But the ROMs provided by OEMs aren't open source. They have privileges to read everything. So is the privileged Google Mobile Suite (Play Services and company). And as I said hardware components aren't open source like BP. So what will you gain by just ensuring that apps are not be able to read the IMEI. The bigger privacy concerns remain unresolved.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/imei-change-and-legality-mods-please-read.4155591